# Replacing a word with $ in groovy

Tags: string, gradle, groovy, replace

I have the following piece of groovy code from a gradle build file I am using for replacing a word in a php file:

```
def str1="My application version is $app_version" 
def str2 = str1.replaceAll('$app_version','2016072601')
println str2​
```

I want to replace $app_version with defined number in this method but somehow it is not working. Do I need to escape or do any special action to perform this replacement?

Comment: "My application version is $app_version" ==> Here app_version a variable must. In groovy if you are using '$' before string with in double inverted comma then it is use as a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings with double quotes and `$` are GStrings, which triggers [Groovy's string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation). Also, [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) receives a regex as first argument, and `$` is a special character in regex, thus, you need to double escape that too.

You can use single quotes OR you can escape the `$` character in your `str1`:

```
def str1='My application version is $app_version'
def str2 = str1.replaceAll('\\$app_version','2016072601')
assert str2 == 'My application version is 2016072601'
```

---

**Update:** Expanding string interpolation a bit, it replaces the `$` placeholder in your string with the variable value of the same name (though not immediately, as it creates an instance of `GString` first). It is roughly akin to this in Java:

```
String str1 = "My application version is " + app_version;
```

So, instead of replacing the variable with `replaceAll`, you could have a variable in your script with the name `app_version`, like `def app_version = "2016072601"` (which is kinda like @BZ.'s answer)

---

**Update 2:** By using string interpolation (as per @BZ.'s answer) or string concatenation, you don't need to use `replaceAll`, but you need a variable called `app_version`:

```
def app_version = '2016072601'
def str1 = "My application version is $app_version"
assert str1 == 'My application version is 2016072601'
```

And with string concatenation you also need a variable called `app_version`:

```
def app_version = '2016072601'
def str1 = "My application version is " + app_version
assert str1 == 'My application version is 2016072601'
```

Comment: Sorry but, Will p, can you please tell me if app_version is a variable then how can you use it in single inverted comma. Here it is use as a String.

Comment: @Omi, I updated my answer. Let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: It is cleared but,
According to your update.
it will also do.
String str1 = "My application version is " + app_version;
def str2 = str1.replaceAll(app_version,'2016072601')
assert str2 == 'My application version is 2016072601'


As per your previous answer when i print value of "str1" it was not given me the actual result.

Comment: By using string interpolation or string concatenation you don't need to use `replaceAll`. I updated my answer. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Yaa Right.. this is what i try to say.. Here it is not required to replace any thing if "app_version " is a variable. Thanks, Will P

Answer (score 0):

Alternately:

```
def versionString = "2016072601"
def string2 = "My application version is $versionString"
```